# Query on Windows Filtering Platform

Tags: c++, windows, windows-vista

I am using the Windows Filtering Platform API to block some URL.

I wanted to know is there any way to block all URLs and give exception to only  a few URLs?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do this.

1. Create a filter that blocks out all URLs
   Have 1 filter block out all requests (0 Conditions set to BLOCK)
2. Allow specific URLs
   Add filters to allow the specific urls you want to let pass.
   Assign the proper filter weights so that filter arbitration reads the ALLOW.

The filter condition you will have to use is based off the IP Address for the

```
FWPM_CONDITION_IP_REMOTE_ADDRESS
```

condition.  You can do a getaddrinfo() call to resolve the url to an address.

It's probably most efficient to be working at the ALE layer:

```
FWPM_LAYER_ALE_AUTH_CONNECT
```

.

Comment: Hi Kema,
thank you for ur inputs
I have tried some thing like what u have told
but i was not able to get the expected result
please refer below link for my other question related to same thing
where u can see code snippet

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458756/blocking-the-url-on-windows-vista